# publishing seed-nonce

Tags: baking

I got a bunch of 0.125 XTZ reward for publishing seed-nonce Binance Baker, Kraken Baker, etc.

I've never seen this before.

What is it for and why was I selected for this many times consecutively?

Comment: It is not clear what the relationship is between "you" and the Binance baker, Kraken baker, etc. And in what sense "you" have been selected (for what?).

Answer (score 1):

The nonce is used to generate the random seed for the chain. Some selected block bakers are required to generate a nonce (if they don't, they lose the rewards for their baked block) and inject them by the end of the next cycle. All those nonces are used to generate a single random seed for the chain.

You just happened to bake an early block of the new cycle where these bakers are injecting their nonces.

Read more about the random seed [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/proof_of_stake.html#random-seed-009) and especially the part about *nonce revelation*.

Answer (score 0):

See this part of the documentation regarding seed nonces: https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/proof_of_stake.html#random-seed